# Get the unique number of entries in column two from table two, where the first column of both tables match

Tags: sqlite, select, unique

I have two tables

```
tmp_CID_EIDs:

EID    
====
1  
2  
3  
5  

EID_PID:

EID    PID
==========
1       99
2       99
3       88
5       99
12      55
18      66
```

I use the following query to get a list of all positions where EID matches in both tables:

```
SELECT EID,
   PID
FROM EID_PID
WHERE EID IN temp_CID_EIDs
```

-->

```
EID   PID
=========
1       99
2       99
3       88
5       99
```

But my final goal is to get the number of unique PIDs from this query.

-->  99
     88

How can I do that? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT PID FROM EID_PID WHERE EID IN tmp_CID_EIDs;
```